# Kernel dies unexpectedly in ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I keep on getting this error.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
for train, test in skf.split(df_new, df_new_target):
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    new = train[:5]
    regr.fit(df_new.iloc[new], df_new_target.iloc[new]) #kernel dies at this line
```

My ipython kernel keeps on dying at the regr.fit line. I thought it was a memory issue as there might be too much data. Hence, i only passed 5 rows to the classifier. But it still killed my kernel with no exception.

Comment: I know this comment is really spoon-feedingly simple, but does the code run without error? And have you tried running it on the normal python shell? Perhaps try running this on the pre-packed IDLE and see what happens.